# Custom Fill Pattern for Graphic Symbol in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, arcgis

[image]

I want to create a custom Fill Pattern for a graphic symbol in Flex as shown in the sample image attached.
Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is Just Basic, you can create more graphics from this like following.

Use [graphics class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS4D7543E0-0BA2-4f5f-92FA-985B6B6315AB.html) for that

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           >

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:BorderContainer 
          height="300" width="300" 
          >
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:BorderContainer borderVisible="false"
        height="100" width="100%" >
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout />
        </s:layout>

    <s:Group>
        <s:Ellipse height="50" width="50">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#000000" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </s:Group>

    <s:Group>
        <s:Ellipse height="50" width="50">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#000000" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </s:Group>

    <s:Group>
        <s:Ellipse height="50" width="50">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#000000" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </s:Group>

    </s:BorderContainer>

    <s:BorderContainer borderVisible="false"
        height="100" width="100%" >
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout />
        </s:layout>

    <s:Group>
        <s:Ellipse height="50" width="50">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#000000" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </s:Group>

    <s:Group>
        <s:Ellipse height="50" width="50">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#000000" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </s:Group>

    <s:Group>
        <s:Ellipse height="50" width="50">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#000000" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </s:Group>

    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:BorderContainer>

</s:Application>
```